# Why there are difference while coding CBOR in Python libraries and RIOT OS C library?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cbor

So I have this thing

```
{'apn': 'censored', 'support_data_mode': False, 'data_usr_name': 'censored', 'data_password': 'censored'}
```

When read this data from system that uses NanoCBOR i get something like this

```
b'\xbfcapnjcensoredqsupport_data_mode\xf4mdata_usr_namedcensoredmdata_passworddcensored\xff'
```

and I can decode it in Python 3 and get correct result. But when I try to encode it back it is like this

```
b'\xa4capnjcensoredqsupport_data_mode\xf4mdata_usr_namedcensoredmdata_passworddcensored'
```

and system doesn't take it back as valid message.

A tried all Python libraries cbor, cbor2 flynn and flunn.

Documentation is sparse and I don't know what to do to encode it in the correct format.

Comment: It seems they are both correct. NanoCBOR uses \xbf to indicate a map with indefinite length, then \xff to indicate the end of the map. Python uses \xa4 to indicate a map with exactly 4 things in it, so \xff is not required at the end. Both are correct CBOR formats. You should see what's wrong with your NanoCBOR system.

Comment: @Marcin Szymczyk - The answer should be posted as an Answer rather than edited into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Yes both formats are correct but that was not the point. The problem was how to create a `\xbf` kind of map in python. And I did it!

```
from flunn import dumps, loads, mapping
dump_map = [('device_id', 1), ('power_status', 1)]
payload = dumps(mapping((a for a in dump_map)))
```

The resulting output is:

```
b'\xbfidevice_id\x01lpower_status\x01\xff'
```

Now the format is as i wanted it and the system accepted it as valid.